# Evaluating $\iiint_B (x^2+y^2+z^2)dV$ where $B$ is the ball of radius $5$ centered at the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral, spheres

The question asks to use spherical coords. My answer is coming out wrong and symbolab is saying I'm evaluating the integrals correctly so my set up must be wrong.

Since $\rho$ is the distance from the origin to a point on it, and it's a sphere, I got $0 \le \rho \le 5$

Since it's a sphere I did $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. And then for $\phi$ I have from $0$ to $\pi$.

From an example problem, $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$

Thus

$$\int^\pi_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^5_0 [( \rho^2) \rho^2 \sin(\phi)]\,d\rho \,d\theta \,d\phi$$

The answer is $\frac{312,500\pi}{7}$ and I'm getting $\frac{-1250}{\pi}$.

Comment: Use \rho with \$ \$ around it to get $\rho$. Use \sin, otherwise it is written in italics. And use \le for less than or equal and \ge for greater than or equal.

Comment: By definition the sum is 25 for all x,y,z on the sphere.

Comment: How on earth did your result end up negative and have a factor of $\pi$ in the denominator?   The answer is $2500\pi$.

Comment: ...apparently by being tired enough that I screwed up evaluating my cos($\phi$)s. I didn't really think to check them considering the answer in the book was so far off from what your saying. I did think the 312k over 7 was a bit... odd.

Comment: The answer is indeed as Dr. MV said, $2500\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Partition your ball $B$ into spherical shells of radius $\rho$ $(0\leq\rho\leq5)$ and thickness $d\rho$. The volume of such a shell is $dV=4\pi \rho^2\,d\rho$. It follows that
$$\int_B \rho^2\>dV=\int_0^5\rho^2\>4\pi\rho^2\>d\rho=2500\pi\ .$$